# $.post function works on my server but not on clients server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

I am making a website for a client, but their server does not support php. Typically how I structure a page is

```
<?php include_once "some php file for header";>
\\page content
<?php include_once "some php file for footer";>
```

Since I can't use php I tried the following method:

```
<script>$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.post('top.html',function( data ){
         $('#top').append(data); });
    $.post('blocks/bottom.html',function( data ){
         $('#bottom').append(data); });
});</script>
<div id="top"></div>
\\content
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

This works fine when I tested it on my 1&1 server, but when I try it on my clients server it does not. I don't think it is an issue with finding "top.html" as the site has the exact same file structure on both servers.

I also did the following to make sure that the append function worked and it did.

```
<script> $( document ).ready(function() {                                
     $('#top').append("<p>Test</p>" );
}); </script>
```

So I believe the problem lies with `$.post`

Can someone give me any input on how I can resolve this issue?  Thank you

Comment: Open the developer toolbar of your browser and look at the Network tab. Can you see the AJAX request being sent? What does the server respond it with?

Comment: Why do you need to `$.post`? Wouldn't you rather use `$.get`?

Comment: Your clients server surely supports some other serverside language, if it doesn't, maybe it's time for your client to get a new server.

Comment: try to use  $('#top').load('top.html');  maybe it work

Comment: You're trying to post to an HTML page? How... how would that work?

Comment: I'll try these, it seems apparent that I don't need post.

Comment: $('#top').load('top.html');  works perfectly, thank you!